What constitutes a linear vs non-linear differential equation
I have a question about what is considered a linear differential equation.
For example, for an arbitary function $y$ with a variable $x, y\cdot dy/dx = 0$ is a non-linear differential equation.
In contrast, $x\cdot dy/dx = 0$ is a linear differential equation.
However, if say $y = x-7$, we can rewrite it as $x = y+7$
In this case then, the linear differential equation $x\cdot dy/dx = 0$ can be rewriten as $(y+7)\cdot dy/dx = 0$, which would be non-linear.
So may I ask, what is wrong with my understanding as there seems to be something wrong as linear and non-linear differential equations should be $2$ seperate groups.
Thank You

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

A differential equation operates on its solutions. If $D$ is the operator that represents the differential equation, e.g. $D=x\frac{d}{dx}$, then we require that $D(f+g)=Df+Dg$ and $D(cf)=cD(f)$.

The classification of "linear" is a property of the equation as given, without any transformations or substitutions applied. It has to be a linear function of $y$ (which also includes its derivatives) in the affine-linear sense.
